# Importing 32-bit reg. file into Win 7 64-bit

Tags: regedit

I am trying to import two 32-bit registry files into a Win 7 64-bit registry. While it says it was 
successful, the changes don't show up. Not in the registry nor in the software I'm using. My goal is to add all my 
Kontakt Sample Libraries into Kontakt's GUI all in one shot. It would save me months of work, instead of adding them 
one at a time. This works perfectly in XP Pro SP3, on every computer I've built. But for the life of me I can't 
figure out how to do it in Win 7 64-bit. I'll upload some pictures to illustrate the point, and hopefully one of 
you Guru's will be able to guide me in the right direction? First of all here's a picture of Win 7 64-bit's 
Registry. It shows the few libraries I've added by hand. A slow and tedious process.

[enter link description here](http://remixshare.com/dl/5ffll/Win%207%2064-bit%20Registry.jpg)

Next is a picture of XP's Registry (how I would like my Win 7 Registry to look) To get these libraries all 
added at once in XP all I did was import these two reg. files. Current User Native Instruments and Local Machine 
Native Instruments. Then all my libraries were populated instantly. The actual libraries and their waves are on my 
E:\ Drive. This is merely a way of pointing to them, so Kontakt can see them. I'll upload those reg. files so 
someone can test adding them to their Registry.

[enter link description here](http://remixshare.com/dl/m1co2/XP's%20Registry.bmp)

Sorry there doesn't seem to be any way to add files to this post. So next is a picture of how Kontakt looks in XP Pro, (the way it should in Win 7.)

(Sorry, a third link or a third picture not permitted without 10 Rep points!!) OMG!!

Hopefully this will make sense to someone? Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? It sure would save me a ton of time, if you could direct me on how to do this correctly. Thanks in advance for your time.

Rob,

P.S. It won't allow me to post pictures or more than 2 links without 10 Rep points. Man, oh man!!

Comment: Have you looked here in your registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node   ?  See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072(v=vs.85).aspx   By the way, neither of your links seems to be pointing anywhere.

Comment: it looks like pictrure links are corrupted :(

Comment: upload your pictures directly here.

Comment: Thank you to you three gentleman who offered to help me it's appreciated. Yes, I'm aware the pictures are corrupt, why I don't know. It would be a helluva lot easier if someone just gave me 10 Rep points so I can post pictures in a proper manner. What a silly rule........time waster really. If you don't like someone or the pictures they upload, surely you can ban their asses easily. But to impede on someone trying to aid the explanation of his issue, is sheer madness.

Comment: And yes, I've tried adding to Wow6432Node, with no results, hence the reason I'm attempting to contact you guys. I will try to upload the pictures to a different Server. and attempt to place them in the correct spot in my initial post. I just can't understand why it has to be so hard? 10 Rep points just to post 3 pictures?..............sheesh!!